# XSLT 1.0: Matching Year Notion, Inch Notion of Numbers. Parsing single field to fill out multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, data-manipulation

**IMPORTANT:** If I need to improve my question in any way to receive help, please let me know, I do my best to document everything.

I have the following Data, in which I tried to remove everything I could to make my question more directly and to provide success and what I have.  I'm struggling with what would be regex in a scripting language. I'm really regretting taking the XSLT approach, as I know nothing about it and I'm way over my head, for such terribly formed data.  On a positive note, I've learned a ton and I'm eternally grateful for the amount of help I've gotten.

I have the node `<partDescription></partDescription>` that contains numbers and text that I need to move to different nodes based on cases, and it's just way too complex for me to understand. I feel that the tokenization approach will solve this problem.

I tried to first `<xsl:variable name="fitment" select="substring-after(partDescription,' for ')"/>` to begin working with the data after the word " for "as most of the data is there.  But I got stuck when trying to find a Year notation (`06) or an Inch notation ("12), but then ranges. But, there are so many cases, that I don't have a clue where to begin :(

Populate `<fitment></fitment>` Node

- Case 1: Populate with the two numbers between a hyphen that each end
  with Double Quotes or Inches and all following `<fitment>18" - 20"</fitment>`
- Case 2: If the two inch range numbers, are after the delimeter " for
  ", then add all text after the numbers `<fitment>15" - 17" Ape Hanger Handlebars</fitment>`
- Case 3: The number, or range of numbers could be in fraction notation
  should be handled the same
  way grab number, and add remaining content `<fitment>1-1/4" Handlebars</fitment>`

Populate `<size></size>` Node

- Case 1: Populate this node if there is a single Number that ends with
  Double Quote, either after "w/ " or by itself. Size will never be a
  range.

Populate `<fitsModel></fitsModel>` Node

- Case 1: There is a year, followed by a model, which is the immediate
  following word `<fitsModel>'17 FL</fitsModel>`

In these two cases, usually, the important content is after the delimiter " for " and the next content is either a year or random text.

- Case 2: There is a range of two years, followed by a model, which immediately follows. `<fitsModel>'00 - '06 Softail</fitsModel>`
- Case 3: Using the delimeter " for " grab the immediate next word
  `<fitsModel>FLHT</fitsModel>`

Sample Data

```
<root>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-7410-00</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06020419</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0602-0419</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>Chrome Hefty Springer Riser for 1-1/4" Handlebars</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-8006KT2B-19M</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06101444</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0610-1444</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>Midnight Cable Kit for 15" - 17" Ape Hanger Handlebars</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-8130KT2-19</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06101314</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0610-1314</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>18" - 20" Stainless Cable Kit for '00 - '06 Softail</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-7340-16B</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06014038</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0601-4038</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>Black 1" Ape Hanger Handlebar w/ 16" Rise</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-7361KT3-14B</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06014057</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0601-4057</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>Black 14" '17 FL Handlebar and Cable Kit</partDescription>
    </part>
    <part>
        <brandName>LA CHOPPERS</brandName>
        <supplierNumber>LA-7352-16</supplierNumber>
        <partNumber>06014546</partNumber>
        <punctuatedPartNumber>0601-4546</punctuatedPartNumber>
        <partStatusDescription>STANDARD</partStatusDescription>
        <partDescription>Chrome 16" Prime Ape for FLHT</partDescription>         
    </part>
</root>
```

Template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="part-by-product" match="part" use="productId" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <items>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="part[partStatusDescription != 'DISCONTINUED']"/>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match="part">
        <item>     
            <xsl:copy-of select="partDescription"/>
           
            <xsl:variable name="finish">
            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Black')">Black</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Flat Back')">Flat Back</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Chrome')">Chrome</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Stainless')">Stainless Steel</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, 'Midnight')">Midnight Stainless</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <finish><xsl:value-of select="$finish"/></finish>
           
            <xsl:variable name="handlebarDiameter">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, '1&quot;')">1"</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, '1-1/4&quot;')">1-1/4"</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(partDescription, '1-1/2&quot;')">1-1/2"</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <handlebarDiameter>
                <xsl:value-of select="$handlebarDiameter"/>
            </handlebarDiameter>
           
            <xsl:variable name="fitmentData" select="substring-after(partDescription,' for ')"/>
            <fitment>
                <xsl:value-of select="$fitmentData"/>
            </fitment>
       
        </item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <partDescription>Chrome Hefty Springer Riser for 1-1/4" Handlebars</partDescription>
        <finish>Chrome</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter>1-1/4"</handlebarDiameter>
        <fitment>1-1/4" Handlebars</fitment>
    </item>
    <item>
        <partDescription>Midnight Cable Kit for 15" - 17" Ape Hanger Handlebars</partDescription>
        <finish>Midnight Stainless</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter/>
        <fitment>15" - 17" Ape Hanger Handlebars</fitment>
    </item>
    <item>
        <partDescription>18" - 20" Stainless Cable Kit for '00 - '06 Softail</partDescription>
        <finish>Stainless Steel</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter/>
        <fitment>18" - 20"</fitment>
        <fitsModel>'00 - '06 Softail</fitsModel>
    </item>
    <item>
        <partDescription>Black 1" Ape Hanger Handlebar w/ 16" Rise</partDescription>
        <finish>Black</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter>1"</handlebarDiameter>
        <fitment/>
        <size>16"</size>
    </item>
    <item>
        <partDescription>Black 14" '17 FL Handlebar and Cable Kit</partDescription>
        <finish>Black</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter/>
        <size>14"</size>
        <fitment/>
        <fitsModel>'17 FL</fitsModel>
    </item>
    <item>
        <partDescription>Chrome 16" Prime Ape for FLHT</partDescription>
        <finish>Chrome</finish>
        <handlebarDiameter/>
        <size>16"</size>
        <fitment/>
        <fitsModel>FLHT</fitsModel>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, you can use a command line XSLT utility nxslt2 or nxslt3. It supports most EXSLT functions, including `split()`,  `tokenize()`, and many others. http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html, http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000047.html

Comment: nxslt 2.2 download: https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/nxslt.shtml

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Sadly it's not an option, as the plugin I use for Magento, only supports vanilla xsl 1.0

Comment: In such case, you can try a raw EXSLT.

Comment: IMHO, your time would be better spent looking for a way to incorporate regex into your workflow - either by calling an external function (if your plugin allows this) or by pre/post-processing the XML using an XSLT 2.0+  processor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that is using nxslt3 that has a built-in EXSLT implementation.

[EXSLT](http://exslt.org/str/index.html)

[nxslt 2.2](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/nxslt.shtml)

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <r>
      <dateModified>2019-10-07T22:28:36</dateModified>
   </r>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exsl date str">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   
   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <root>
         <before>
            <xsl:value-of select="r/dateModified"/>
         </before>
         <after>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:format-date(r/dateModified,'yyyy-MMM-dd')"/>
         </after>
         <now>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>
         </now>
         <year>
            <xsl:value-of select="date:year(date:date-time())"/>
         </year>
         <split attr="a, simple, list">
            <xsl:for-each select="str:split('a, simple, list', ', ')">
               <r>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </r>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </split>
         <tokenize attr="{date:date-time()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(date:date-time(), '-T:')">
               <r>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </r>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tokenize>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <before>2019-10-07T22:28:36</before>
  <after>2019-Oct-07</after>
  <now>2020-12-26T23:53:13-05:00</now>
  <year>2020</year>
  <split attr="a, simple, list">
    <r>a</r>
    <r>simple</r>
    <r>list</r>
  </split>
  <tokenize attr="2020-12-26T23:53:13-05:00">
    <r>2020</r>
    <r>12</r>
    <r>26</r>
    <r>23</r>
    <r>53</r>
    <r>13</r>
    <r>05</r>
    <r>00</r>
  </tokenize>
</root>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this helps? As the output doesn't match the requirements

Comment: Because you are confined to XSLT 1.0, nxslt XSLT processor is arguably a best XSLT processor for your scenario. It has a built-in EXSLT implementation. EXSLT has all the functionality you need: `split(), tokenize()`, and REGEX functions, and much more.

Comment: It is a conceptual example for you. Just to show you use of unavailable functionality in XSLT 1.0